# How to tar a directory from different - different server and copy to current server on which I am working

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Actually I want to tar a directory from different-different server and need to move that tar to my current server on which I am working so I am writing a shell script for that and had used the following command for this

```
ssh hostname " tar -cvj site1.tar.gz -C /www/logs/test " > site2.tar.gz
```

I had also tried moving it to a directory on my current server but not able to achieve that also, command tried -

```
ssh hostname " tar -cvj site1.tar.gz -C /www/logs/test " > /www/logs/automate
```

I tried this and think that it will not work, so is their any other way to achieve this, Please help. It will be appreciable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU tar:

```
ssh hostname "tar -C /www/logs/test -cjf -" > your.tar.bz2
```

> `-f -`: write archive to stdout